# How to blend local cubemaps?

Tags: fragment-shader, blending, cubemap

I have a (GPU) Buffer that contains the World Position and Extents of Local Cubemaps aswell as a TextureArray that contains the textures of the Cubemaps.
The Bounds of the Local Cubemaps are Axis Aligned, there is no rotation involved.

How do I figure out which and how much cubemaps affect a single pixel (in a pixel shader), when Extents can overlap (arbitrary deep)?
[image]

Comment: What do these cubemaps represent in this case? Are they reflection probes, or something else?

Comment: @DMGregory yes, they are for reflections